# Pandas - finding the row blocks of size n where the highest value is exactly in the middle without using for cycle

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Is there a way in pandas dataframe to locate all the row blocks of size n where the highest value is exactly in the middle? What i need is to create an extra column which only has values of the middle biggest value of each such block.
Here is the example using for cycle and block size 5:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 2, 2, 5],
              columns = ['number'])
for i in range(2, len(df) - 2):
    if (df.loc[i, 'number'] > df.loc[i - 1, 'number'] and\
        df.loc[i, 'number'] > df.loc[i - 2, 'number'] and\
        df.loc[i, 'number'] > df.loc[i + 1, 'number'] and\
        df.loc[i, 'number'] > df.loc[i + 2, 'number']):
        df.loc[i, 'high'] = df.loc[i, 'number']
```

Output:

```
    number  high
0   1   None
1   2   None
2   3   3
3   2   None
4   1   None
5   2   None
6   1   None
7   4   4
8   3   None
9   2   None
10  1   None
11  5   5
12  2   None
13  2   None
14  5   None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with the parameter `center=True`.  Take the max of this, and compare it to your target.

```
def highest_in(s, n):
    test = s.rolling(window=n, center=True).max() == s
    return s.where(test, None)

df['high'] = highest_in(df.number, n=5)
print(df)
    # number  high
# 0        1  None
# 1        2  None
# 2        3     3
# 3        2  None
# 4        1  None
# 5        2  None
# 6        1  None
# 7        4     4
# 8        3  None
# 9        2  None
# 10       1  None
# 11       5     5
# 12       2  None
# 13       2  None
# 14       5  None
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful, also there one small problem - this method seems to return values which are not strictly bigger - for example if I have a block of values [3, 3, 3, 2, 2] it will return the 3 in the middle, but it is easy to pick up from here, thanks again!

Comment: @Brad Solomon nice solution. What do you think about mine

Answer (score 1):

We can also use argrelextrema from scipy to get local maximas in order. Here order is 2 to consider 2 numbers above and 2 numbers  below. By consider the value the block size will be five.

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
maxInd = argrelextrema(df.number.values, np.greater, order=2)

df['new'] = df.iloc[maxInd]['high']
```

Output :

```
   number  new
0        1  NaN
1        2  NaN
2        3  3.0
3        2  NaN
4        1  NaN
5        2  NaN
6        1  NaN
7        4  4.0
8        3  NaN
9        2  NaN
10       1  NaN
11       5  5.0
12       2  NaN
13       2  NaN
14       5  NaN
```